# Spoilers in the Wiki?

Tags: discussion, spoilers, tag-wiki

Should I be including information in a Tag Wiki that could be considered a spoiler?

My initial thoughts:

- Never including any spoiler info in the Except.
- Allow spoiler info in the Wiki, since it requires a deliberate click, indicating the user is looking for further information.
- Add spoiler markup in the Wiki for spoilers?

Are there any guidelines, rules or accepted practice for spoilers in Wikis?

Comment: I tried to keep spoilers out of the Tag Wiki for "Book of Eli" (regarding the book), but found it difficult to write a Wiki that didn't have at least something that could be considered a spoiler. I'm happy to go back and re-write, but need some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I approved your edit, I don't think spoilers ought to be in the tag descriptions.  All it takes is a mouseover to bring up the description; the user has no warning and their eyes will naturally track right to the information.  There's no way to offer spoiler protection except by not having the spoiler there in the first place.

Comment: You're saying spoilers shouldn't be in the Excerpt nor the Wiki? I'll go back and edit the Wiki (assuming no-one else has done it in the meantime).

Comment: So, wait ... the expectation for tag wikis is that there should be no spoilers? The Wikipedia itself provides spoilers. I understand not wanting spoilers as the title or first line of a post, but a tag wiki? Common sense would seem to dictate that if you click a link with the word "Wiki" in it, you're going to get relevant information and, yes, possibly spoilers. Does Stack Exchange itself have a site-wide policy on spoilers?

Comment: @aSlytherin Wikipedia's not the best example.  They used to do spoiler tags, but some industrious editor used an automated script one day to remove *all* the spoiler tags.  In the aftermath, they decided to leave the site as-is, and to make spoilers verboten.