# Are spoilers acceptable in tag wikis?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spoliers in the Wiki?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/spoliers-in-the-wiki)

The book-of-eli tag contains a spoiler for the end of the movie.  Are such spoilers acceptable in tag descriptions?

Comment: Looks like we have 2 questions about the same issue here.

Comment: @Keen Sorry.  I did try "tag wiki spoilers" in the search.

Comment: Heh, the two of you posted around the same time.